# Change squid3 access.log

Tags: squid, logging

Where lies the config file to change the output of the access.log file?
I want to remove the website the user was browsing and format the time so it's human readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a custom log format in squid.conf with the [`logformat` directive](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/logformat/). This can then be used in the [`access_log` directive](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/access_log/):

```
logformat nourl  %tl %6tr %>a %Ss/%03>Hs %<st %[un %Sh/%<a %mt
access_log daemon:/usr/local/squid/var/logs/access.log nourl
```

will output a log file similar to the squid default, with time in local time and HTTP method and URL removed.

Comment: Awesome. Worked like a charm!
The only thing that didn't work, was the last bit of logformat. "%<a %mt" should be a capital 'a'. And at first I didn't know that you have to set it up in /etc/squid3/squid.conf file. Thought it was kinda misleading to write "This can then be used within access_log". Should rather be "within squid.conf". Thanks though.

Comment: Glad it worked, and sorry for confusion - I did link to the documentation so thought it might make it clear (although I see now that it's not clear that the `directives` don't look like hyperlinks). I've modified the answer for future reference.

Comment: Thanks for this, wanted to log the proxy username, and helped me too. It was %un btw